# What is the difference between read() and fread()?

Tags: c, file, file-io

I'm reading source code of the linux tool [badblocks](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/). They use the `read()` function there. Is there a difference to the standard C `fread()` function? (I'm not counting the arguments as a difference.)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`read()` is a low level, unbuffered read. It makes a direct system call on UNIX.

`fread()` is part of the C library, and provides buffered reads.  It is usually implemented by calling `read()` in order to fill its buffer.

Comment: So there are 3 buffers? The harddrive has one, /dev/hda is buffered too and fread. Is this correct?

Comment: yes. you can flush the third one using "fflush", the second one using fsync. i don't know of a way to flush the harddrive buffer.

Comment: fflush() only really applies to fwrite(), which has the same relation to write() that fread() has to read().

Comment: @Darron im more of a Linux guy and question was about Linux. It can differ per OS but in general one can assume that in Linux fread calls read.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Is my understanding correct: read is not actually a completely "unbuffered" read, in the sense that it enjoys at least hard drive disk buffer and os-level buffer? The only buffer it misses, is the library-level buffer which is offered by fread?

Answer (score 50):

Family `read()` -> *`open`, `close`, `read`, `write`*
Family `fread()` -> *`fopen`, `fclose`, `fread`, `fwrite`*

### Family read:

- are system calls
- are not formatted IO: we have a non formatted byte stream

### Family fread

- are functions of the standard C library (libc)
- use an internal buffer
- are formatted IO (with the "%.." parameter) for some of them
- use always the Linux buffer cache

More details [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t437072-read-vs-fread.html), although note that this post contains some incorrect information.

Comment: The last two bullet points in both the read and fread lists are nonsense. Both families use the buffer cache by default, and which one to use has **nothing** to do with whether you are accessing a character device, a block device, or a regular file.

Comment: AIB is confusing two layers of buffering -- the kernel buffering happens in both cases (what I would normally call the Linux buffer cache) but buffering that is done in userspace to reduce the total number of system calls I think only happens with fread.

Comment: @Marcus I've removed most of the misconceptions from the answer.

Comment: Technically family read are not syscalls. It's the standard C library (libc) too. `read()` is a bit "thinner" wrapper over the syscall than `fread()`

Answer (score 12):

As I remember it the `read()` level APIs do not do buffering - so if you `read()` 1 byte at a time you will have a huge perf penalty compared to doing the same thing with `fread()`. `fread()` will pull a block and dole it out as you ask for it.  `read()` will drop to the kernel for each call.

Answer (score 10):

`read` is a syscall, whereas `fread` is a function in the C standard library.

Comment: @Jānis Gruzis, that depends on the implementation of `fread`. Mainly because there is no guarantee that the system call `read` is available. [Wikipedia `read` page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_\(system_call\))

Comment: @JānisGruzis I just checked if it's the same on Windows and to my amazement I discovered that [**their `read` is deprecated**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235412.aspx). Presumably their [`fread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt0etdcs.aspx) calls `_read` and not `read`? In any case it seems that not every `fread` must call `read`.

Answer (score 5):

One difference you should be aware of if you are converting code that uses one to using the other:

- `fread` blocks until the number of bytes you asked for has been read, or the file ends, or an error occurs.
- `read` also blocks, but if you ask for say 4kB it may return after reading just 1kB, even if the file has not ended.

This can cause subtle bugs, as it depends on where the file is stored, caches, etc.

Answer (score 2):

read() --> Directly using this system call to kernel and that performs the IO operation.

fread() --> Is a function provided in standard library.

Calling `fread()` is mainly used for binary file data where struct data are stored. 
The main difference between these two is the number of system calls in your application.

The `fread()` kind of standard IO library functions are optimized for system calls, rather your application making system calls.

Answer (score 1):

For Beginners like me in C/Systems programming domain. I am roughly quoting the answer from the lecture around [this](https://youtu.be/WHmmT_syaG8?t=4091) timestamp by Professor John Kubiatowicz.

`fread` is a high level C-API that internally uses the low-level `read` system call in an optimized way.

Imagine your system is optimized to read 4k bytes at a time. When you use `fread` to read from a file in a while loop, you will initiate `read` system call once to get a chunk of 4k bytes from the kernel and save it in user buffer. Now, all the subsequent reading for upto 4k bytes will happen from that user buffer.
This is good because system calls are expensive.

This is also highlighted by the comment from @Joseph Garvin in his comment above.