# Doing file operations with 64-bit addresses in C + MinGW32

Tags: cygwin, mingw, large-file-support

I'm trying to read in a 24 GB XML file in C, but it won't work.  I'm printing out the current position using ftell() as I read it in, but once it gets to a big enough number, it goes back to a small number and starts over, never even getting 20% through the file.  I assume this is a problem with the range of the variable that's used to store the position (long), which can go up to about 4,000,000,000 according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(VS.80).aspx, while my file is 25,000,000,000 bytes in size.  A long long should work, but how would I change what my compiler([Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)/[mingw32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW)) uses or get it to have fopen64?

Comment: wow, a 24GB XML file.

Comment: Its wikipedia(the whole thing)

Comment: I dont have internet lots of the time, and I think wikipedia would be useful, so I downloaded it, and now im trying to compress it and make a reader for it

Comment: Do you actually fail to read the file in, or just fail to find the size of the file?

Comment: Fail to read it.  Im going through the file, finding all the titles in the first stage, and storing them along with their position, and then ill go through again, and compress the articles in chunks, indexing them in a main file, but it never gets through the file, since the position wraps around, and I start reading the beginning again

Comment: Off topic, but I'm a little surprised all of wikipedia is only 24gigs (including XML overhead)

Comment: Me too, but it actually seems pretty close... 24 billion letters...(its only english)...  It sure looks like it has everything(just from browsing the titles my program prints out.  Plus, take a look at encyclopedia for ipod(where I got the idea), they fit the entire thing in 1-2GB, and display it on an iPod

Comment: If you successfully read that file, you could say "I'd read entire Wikipedia"

Comment: Assuming that's just text, I'm surprised it's that **large**.  A standard (hard-copy) encyclopedia has about, say, 4KB of text per page (~90 columns, 50 rows).  Say, 700 pages per alphabetical*26
 volumes, 73MB/World Book.  Round up to 100MB.  So, Wikipedia is 240 World Books.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/news/2009/10/openmoko-offline-reader-puts-wikipedia-in-your-pocket.ars

Comment: I know your programming question is good and valid, but aren't there some existing offline wikipedia tools? I saw this but don't know if it is of interest to you (maybe you just want the fun of doing it yourself): http://blog.fupps.com/2008/05/20/wikitaxi-use-a-local-copy-of-wikipedia/

Comment: @mocj: I was just going to suggest that.  I have one of the OpenMoko freerunner phones.  Cool device, though clearly a beta.  IIRC, the new wiki reader thingy has 3 million articles and it takes 4GB.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta Wikipedia is *huge*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Size_of_English_Wikipedia_in_August_2007.svg

Comment: @Tim: that looks like about 63 World Books.  It might have gotten within spitting distance of my estimate in the two years since.

Comment: its about 6.3 million articles

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use wget or something similar to just download each page, etc., as an individual file? File systems are very good at dealing with things like this :)

Comment: I'm not a C programmer, but couldn't you use a memory mapped file?

Answer (score 3):

The `ftell()` function typically returns an `unsigned long`, which only goes up to 2<sup>32</sup> bytes (4 GB) on 32-bit systems. So you can't get the file offset for a 24 GB file to fit into a 32-bit `long`.

You may have the `ftell64()` function available, or the standard `fgetpos()` function may return a larger offset to you.

Comment: I dont have ftell64(), and fgetpos() returns the same thing as ftell()

Answer (score 3):

You might try using the OS provided file functions [CreateFile and ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540534(VS.85).aspx).  According to the [File Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364397(VS.85).aspx) topic, the position is stored as a 64bit value.

Comment: Don't scare people, those are C functions and part of the windows API :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can use a 64-bit method as suggested by Loadmaster, I think you will have to break the file up.

[This resource](http://www.nabble.com/MINGW-I-O-support-for-file-sizes-%3E-2GB-(LFS-support)-td17205780.html) seems to suggest it is possible using _telli64(). I can't test this though, as I don't use mingw.

Comment: But theres no compiler option or anything to enable them?  I can see them in the include files, but theyre under an #ifdef.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do this in one file, a bit of a hack but if splitting the file up properly isn't a real option, you could write a few functions that temp split the file, one that uses ftell() to move through the file and swaps ftell() to a new file when its reaching the split point, then another that stitches the files back together before exiting. An absolutely botched up approach, but if no better solution comes to light it could be a way to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  Instead of using fopen, fseek, fread, fwrite...  I'm using _open, lseeki64, read, write.  And I am able to write and seek in > 4GB files.

Edit:  It seems the latter functions are about 6x slower than the former ones.  I'll give the bounty anyone who can explain that.

Edit:  Oh, I learned here that read() and friends are unbuffered.   [What is the difference between read() and fread()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584142/what-is-the-difference-between-read-and-fread)

Answer (score -1):

Even if the ftell() in the Microsoft C library returns a 32-bit value and thus obviously will return bogus values once you reach 2 GB, just reading the file should still work fine. Or do you need to seek around in the file, too? For that you need _ftelli64() and _fseeki64().

Note that unlike some Unix systems, you don't need any special flag when opening the file to indicate that it is in some "64-bit mode". The underlying Win32 API handles large files just fine.