# LD_PRELOAD with file functions

Tags: linux, function, overriding, ld-preload

I have a rather peculiar file format to work with:
Every line begins with the checksum of its content, followed by a new-line-character.

It looks like this:

```
[CHECKSUM OF LINE_1][LINE_1]\n
[CHECKSUM OF LINE_2][LINE_2]\n
[CHECKSUM OF LINE_3][LINE_3]\n
...
```

My goal: To allow any application to work with these files like they would work with any other text file - unaware of the additional checksums at the beginning of each line.

Since I work on a linux machine with debian wheezy (kernel 3.18.26) I want to use the LD_PRELOAD-mechanism to override the relevant file functions.
I have seen something like this with zlibc on https://zlibc.linux.lu/index.html - with an explanation of how it works ( https://zlibc.linux.lu/zlibc.html#SEC8 ).

But I dont get it. They only replace the file-opening functions. No read. No write. no fseek. Nothing. So how does it work?
Or - which functions would I have to intercept to handle every read or write operation on this file and handle them accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't exactly check how it works but the reason seems to be quite simple.

Possible implementation:

zlibc open:

1. uncompress file you wanted to open to some temporary file
2. open this temporary file instead of yours

zlibc close:

1. Compress temporary file
2. Override original file

In this case you don't need to override read/write/etc because you can use original ones.

In your case you have two possible solutions:

1. `open`, that make a copy of your file with striped checksums. `close` that calculates checksums and override original file
2. `read` and `write` that are able to skip/calculate checksums.

Ad 2.
From [What is the difference between read() and fread()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584142/what-is-the-difference-between-read-and-fread):

> fread() is part of the C library, and provides buffered reads. It is
>   **usually** implemented by calling read() in order to fill its buffer

In this case I believe that overriding `open` and `close` will be less error prone because you can safely reuse original `read`, `write`, `fread`, `fseek` etc.

Comment: That does sound like a reasonable approach.
Am I correct in my assumption, that all functions like `fopen`, `fclose`, `fgets`, `fputs`, `fread`, `fwrite`, etc... all are library functions which - at some point - use the system calls you mentioned?
What about functions like `fseek` and `ftell`?
Are there any other system calls I should intercept to make sure everything works fine?